# CBCT GPU Reconstruction

Tags: opencl

The below openCL code works pretty good and pretty fast, but I have the impression that I'm missing something in terms of openCL barrier and in therm of index mix; I know that is not very easy to understand, it is the kernel of a CBCT reconstruction I'm working on; the finale image (ReturnMatrice looks a little confused).

```
 __kernel void
                   ReconstructionGPU(
                                       __global          float* Matrice,
                                       __global          float* ReturnMatrice,
                                       __global          short* ReturnCheckImage,
                                       __constant        float* _dLocArraiAngoliSen,
                                       __constant        float* _dLocArraiAngoliCos,
                                       __constant        float* Cos_Tilt_in_Rad,
                                       __constant        float* Sin_Tilt_in_Rad,
                                       __constant        float* iTilt,
                                       __constant        float* _iOffsetU,
                                       __constant        float* _iOffsetV,
                                       __constant        int* iSizeX,
                                       __constant        int* iSizeY,
                                       __constant        int* iSizeZ,
                                       __constant        int* iSizeImgX,
                                       __constant        int* iSizeImgY,
                                       __constant        float* _fDSO,
                                       __constant        float* _fDSD,
                                       __constant        float* m_fSizeVoxelX,
                                       __constant        float* m_fSizeVoxelY,
                                       __constant        float* m_fPixelSensoreDim,
                                       __constant        int* Loop,
                                       __constant        int* Axial,
                                       __constant        int* Padding
                                   )
        {

        private int _iLocSizeX = iSizeX[0];                     // Detector X
        private int _iLocSizeY = iSizeY[0];                     // Detector Y
        private int _iLocSizeImage = _iLocSizeX * _iLocSizeY;   // Dimensione Immagine

        private int _iSizeMezziX;                               // EmiMatrix X
        _iSizeMezziX = (iSizeX[0] / 2 );
        
        private int _iSizeMezziY;
        _iSizeMezziY = (iSizeY[0] / 2 );                        // EmiMatrix Y
                            
        private int _iSizeMezziDetX;                            // Emidetector X
        _iSizeMezziDetX = (iSizeImgX[0] / 2 );
        private int _iSizeMezziDetY;
        _iSizeMezziDetY = (iSizeImgY[0] / 2 );                  // Emidetector Y
                            
        private float _iSizeMezziYQuadro = ((_iSizeMezziX - Padding[0]) * (_iSizeMezziY - Padding[0]));   //Border

        private float kySen = 0;
        private float kyCos = 0;

        private float CoordY_Piu_OffsetU = 0;

        private float CoordZ_Piu_OffsetV = 0;
        private float fDist_Y_inMmObj = 0;

        private float fDist_Z_inMmObj = 0;
        private float fDSDinMmY = 0;

        private float fDSDinMmZ = 0;

        private float fDSDinMmYPiu_AngoloTilt = 0;

        private float fDSDinMmZPiu_AngoloTilt = 0;

        private float _ValImage = 0;


        private int ValY = 0;

        private int ValZ = 0;

        private int _iTempx = 0;
        private int _iTempy = 0;

        private int _Index = 0;

        private int z = 0;

        private int zMenoAxial0 = 0;

        private float zPerIlockSizeImage = 0;

        private float TempYPerIlockSizeX = 0;

        private float zPiuTyLoc = 0;

        private float zMenoAxTyLoc = 0;

        private int m_y;
        private int m_x;
        private int y;
        private int x;

        private int m_z = get_global_id(2);

        z = m_z + Axial[0];                             

                                m_y = get_global_id(1);
                                m_x = get_global_id(0);

                                y = (m_y - _iSizeMezziY ) ;
                                x = (m_x - _iSizeMezziX) ;

                                CoordZ_Piu_OffsetV  = -_iSizeMezziX + z  +     _iOffsetV[0];
                                fDist_Z_inMmObj     = CoordZ_Piu_OffsetV * m_fSizeVoxelX[0];             

                                zMenoAxial0        = (z - Axial[0] )   * _iLocSizeImage ;
                                zPerIlockSizeImage = z                 * _iLocSizeImage;

                                    kySen = (_dLocArraiAngoliSen[Loop[0]] * (y)) ;
                                    kyCos = (_dLocArraiAngoliCos[Loop[0]] * (y)) ;                                                                       
                        
                                    CoordY_Piu_OffsetU      = y  - _iOffsetU[0];
                                    
                                    fDist_Y_inMmObj     = (CoordY_Piu_OffsetU * m_fSizeVoxelY[0]);           // Distanza Y in millimetri del voxel in esame nel volume ricostruito
                                                                                                           
                                    fDSDinMmY                   = 0;

                                    fDSDinMmYPiu_AngoloTilt     = 0;
                                    
                                    ValY                        = 0;                                
                                    
                                    fDSDinMmZ                   = 0;                                        
                                    
                                    fDSDinMmZPiu_AngoloTilt     = 0;
                                    
                                    ValZ                        = 0;                                                                      

                                        _iTempx    =  ((_iSizeMezziX + (_dLocArraiAngoliCos[Loop[0]] * x)   - kySen));       // Calcolo coordinate X
                                        _iTempy    =  ((_iSizeMezziY + (_dLocArraiAngoliSen[Loop[0]] * x)   + kyCos));       // Calcolo coordinate Y
                                    
                                        // Calcoli salti per assegnazione matrice ricostruita

                                        TempYPerIlockSizeX =   _iTempy * iSizeX[0];

                                        zPiuTyLoc     = zPerIlockSizeImage + TempYPerIlockSizeX;                                        
                                      
                                        zMenoAxTyLoc  = zMenoAxial0 + TempYPerIlockSizeX;                                                                               
                                        
                                        if (_iTempy >= iSizeY - Padding[0] || _iTempx >= iSizeX - Padding[0] || _iTempy< 0 || _iTempx< 0  || 
                                          (((_iTempx - _iSizeMezziX) * (_iTempx - _iSizeMezziX)) + ((_iTempy - _iSizeMezziY) * (_iTempy - _iSizeMezziY))) > _iSizeMezziYQuadro)
                                           
                                        { }
                                        else
                                        {

                                            //float fKval = (_fDSO[0] - (x * m_fSizeVoxelX[0]));
                                            float fKval = (_fDSO[0] - (x * m_fPixelSensoreDim[0]));

                                            fDSDinMmY    = ((fDist_Y_inMmObj* _fDSD[0]) / fKval);         // Distanza Y del pixel in esame rapportata a DSD in millimetri                                                                               
                                            fDSDinMmZ    = ((fDist_Z_inMmObj* _fDSD[0]) / fKval);         // Distanza DSD in millimetri
                                            
                                            if (iTilt != 0)
                                            {

                                                fDSDinMmYPiu_AngoloTilt = (fDSDinMmY * Cos_Tilt_in_Rad[0] +0.5f);                               // Calcolo della Coordinata che tiene conto anche dell'angolo di inclinazione del sensore
                                                
                                                ValY = (((fDSDinMmYPiu_AngoloTilt / m_fPixelSensoreDim[0] ) + _iSizeMezziDetX)+0.5f);   // Distanza in pixel del pixel in esame sul detector       
                                                                                        
                                                fDSDinMmZPiu_AngoloTilt = (fDSDinMmZ  + (fDSDinMmZ * Sin_Tilt_in_Rad[0])+0.5f);                 // Calcolo della Coordinata che tiene conto anche dell'angolo di inclinazione del sensore

                                                ValZ = (((fDSDinMmZPiu_AngoloTilt / m_fPixelSensoreDim[0]) + _iSizeMezziDetY)+0.5f);    // Distanza in pixel del pixel in esame sul detector
                                                                                
                                            }   

                                            else
                                            {
                                                
                                                ValY = ((fDSDinMmY / m_fPixelSensoreDim[0]) + _iSizeMezziDetX+0.5f);                 // Distanza in pixel del pixel in esame sul detector

                                                ValZ = ((fDSDinMmZ / m_fPixelSensoreDim[0]) + _iSizeMezziDetY+0.5f);                 // Distanza in pixel del pixel in esame sul detector                                       

                                            }
                                                                                   
                                            if (ValY >= 0 && ValY < iSizeImgX[0] && ValZ >= 0 && ValZ < iSizeImgY[0])
                                                {
                                                
                                                _Index  = ((ValZ * iSizeImgX[0]) + ValY);
                                                
                                                                                                 
                                                _ValImage = (float)Matrice[_Index];//  Pixel dell'immagine con coordinate calcolate da ValX e ValY                                                
                                                                                                     
                                                }
                                            else 
                                                { 

                                                 _ValImage = 0;     // Pixel dell'immagine con coordinate calcolate da ValX e ValY                                                
                                   
                                                }
                                                                                                                                                                
                                                   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

                                                            ReturnMatrice[(int)zMenoAxTyLoc + _iTempx] += _ValImage;   //ValImgPesato                                                    


                                                            _ValImage = 0;                                                          
                                              
                                                }                                               
              
                }
```

Comment: Use the most minimal code sample you can think of. Also, barriers generally are not a good idea in potentially diverging code paths (think if branches and loops) unless all cores in the warp take the same branch (in that case the branch is effectively fixed)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, mine is a backprojection  that is solved from triple (Z,Y,X) for that calculate the position of a Pixel in a volume, all thread access together to the VRAM to give the result that is similiar to a 3D Cluod Point (in really is a straight array). Looking at the result, that is a 3D volume, it seems that is somehow mixed...

Comment: Okay... and what is the question?

Comment: When I got the result, it seems like if the index is mixing the final value, I thought that it could be a problem with the use of a barrier